# How can I change the header colour in a default template oneside article?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, article

```
\documentclass[
10pt, % Main document font size
a4paper, % Paper type, use 'letterpaper' for US Letter paper
oneside, % One page layout (no page indentation)
%twoside, % Two page layout (page indentation for binding and different headers)
headinclude,footinclude, % Extra spacing for the header and footer
BCOR5mm, % Binding correction
]{scrartcl}

 \input{structure5.tex} % Include the structure.tex file which specified the document structure and layout

\hyphenation{Fortran hy-phen-ation} % Specify custom hyphenation points in words with dashes where you would like hyphenation to occur, or alternatively, don't put any dashes in a word to stop hyphenation altogether
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm} % Math packages
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{~#1}}} % The header for all pages (oneside) or for even pages (twoside)
%\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection~#1}} % Uncomment when using the twoside option - this modifies the header on odd pages
 The header style
\lehead{\mbox{\llap{\small\thepage\kern1em\color{halfgray} \vline}\color{halfgray}\hspace{0.5em}\rightmark\hfil}} % The header style
\pagestyle{scrheadings} % Enable the headers specified in this block
```

I've tried to replace "halfgray" with "black" but nothig happens.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: I can't compile your code, even with some adjustments.  Please provide a complete minimal working example, i.e. a short bit of code that demonstrates the problem and that others can cut and paste into their editor and compile verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't the color. With the opion `oneside` Koma-script uses `\lohead`, `\cohead`, and `\rohead`. But `\lehead`, `\cehead`, and `\rehead` are not used. So by replacing `\lehead` with `\lohead` it should work:

```
\documentclass[
10pt, % Main document font size
a4paper, % Paper type, use 'letterpaper' for US Letter paper
oneside, % One page layout (no page indentation)
%twoside, % Two page layout (page indentation for binding and different headers)
headinclude,footinclude, % Extra spacing for the header and footer
BCOR5mm, % Binding correction
]{scrartcl}

%\input{structure5.tex} % we don't have this file!

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADERS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{{~#1}}} % \spacedlowsmallcaps removed, package for this unknown

\clearscrheadings % to clear all header and foot parts
\lohead{\mbox{\llap{\small\thepage\kern1em\color{red} \vline}\color{red}\hspace{0.5em}\rightmark\hfil}} % color halfgray is undefined
\pagestyle{scrheadings} % Enable the headers specified in this block

\begin{document}
\section{Lipsum 1}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

If this doen't help, you need to provide us with a proper [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), which shows your problem without having us guessing what packages to use. Also, please reduce the packages loaded to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the usage of `\spacedsmallcaps` I assume that package `scrlayer-scrpage` is loaded. This package is the successor of the deprecated `scrpage2`.

So I would use:

```
\documentclass[
10pt,
%a4paper,% default
%oneside,% default
%twoside,
headinclude,footinclude,
BCOR=5mm, % changed syntax!!
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{color}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \mbox{\rightmark\hspace{0.5em}\rlap{\vline\kern1em\pagemark}}%
  \else
    \mbox{\llap{\pagemark\kern1em\vline}\hspace{0.5em}\rightmark}%
  \fi
}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\small}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\color{red}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{~#1}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Lipsum 1}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

And if you enable `twoside`:

[image]

If the headline should not be aligned at the inner instead the outer margin of the text area, you can replace `\ohead{...}` by

```
\ihead{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \mbox{\llap{\pagemark\kern1em\vline}\hspace{0.5em}\rightmark}%
  \else
    \mbox{\rightmark\hspace{0.5em}\rlap{\vline\kern1em\pagemark}}%
  \fi
}
```

Result for a onesided document:

[image]

and with `twoside`:

[image]